# Sass pass map to a function isn't a valid CSS value

Tags: css, sass

I have a function that accepts sass `map` as a parameter. The problem is that when I give it a custom `map` it throws:

> (color: red) isn't a valid CSS value.

```
@function is-map($var){
  @return type-of($var) == 'map';
}

@function someFunc($props...) {
  @if(is-map($props)) {
    @return 'map';
  } @else {
    @return $props;
  }
}

h2 {
  color: someFunc((color: red));
}
```

I am expecting to get inside the if block and to return the `'map'` string. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your map, but with your usage of the `$props...`:

```
@function is-map($var){
  @return type-of($var) == 'map';
}

@function someFunc($props...) {
  @if(is-map($props...)) { /*  only difference is the three dots you don't use */
    @return 'map';
  } @else {
    @return $props;
  }
}

h2 {
  color: someFunc((color: red));
}
```

Please read this [site point article about SASS `@function` arguments](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-multiple-arguments-lists-or-arglist/).